# How can i send data to Contract's function with sendTransaction?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, nodejs

i hava contract like this

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Sample {
    string public name = "sample";

    function set(string memory _name) public {
        name = _name;
    }

    function get() public view returns (string memory) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and i want to send data to contract's function named 'set'. Like this:

```js
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result) {
    web3.eth.sendTransaction(
        {from:"0xaD950d2Ae9234900B59F9fb16202a195D9fbC74a",
        to:"0x887499e273Cf6f7a5135E3BA5E4fce89A8D0b15E",
        data: "0xdf"
            }, function(err, transactionHash) {
      if (!err)
        console.log(transactionHash + " success"); 
    });
});
```

but how can i specify function name('get') in below code? Then i want to see the change in following code:

```
sampleContract.methods.get().call()
    .then(result => console.log('Sonuç: ' + result))
    .catch(error => console.log('An error occured! --> ' + error));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just looking for this?

```js
sampleContract.methods.set("myname").send({ from: "0xaD950d2Ae9234900B59F9fb16202a195D9fbC74a" })
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector of the function is made of the first 4 bytes of the hash of the function name and parameter types. In your case the data field is calculated by first getting the hash of the function name: `sha3('get()')` then get the first 4 bytes of that as your data.

If the function has parameters, for instance:  `myfunction(uint256 value1, uint256 value2)`

First get first 4 bytes of `sha3('myfunction(uint256,uint256)')` and then concatenete the result with the variables value1 and value2: `(4bytes,values1,values2)`

Hope this helps

Comment: sorry i made mistake. i meant to write "set". now how can write set function with parameter?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Function is specified by the first 4 bytes of transaction data, that should be equal to the first 4 bytes of keccak256 hash code of the signature of the function.  Signature of `get` function is `get()`, keccak256 of this signature is `0x6D4CE63CAA65600744AC797760560DA39EBD16E8240936B51F53368EF9E0E01F`, first four bytes are `0x6D4CE63C`, so you need to do something like this:

```js
web3.eth.getAccounts (
  function (error, result) {
    web3.eth.sendTransaction (
      {
        from:"0xaD950d2Ae9234900B59F9fb16202a195D9fbC74a",
        to:"0x887499e273Cf6f7a5135E3BA5E4fce89A8D0b15E",
        data: "0x6D4CE63C"
      },
      function (err, transactionHash) {
        if (!err)
          console.log(transactionHash + " success"); 
      }
    );
  }
);
```

In case you need to send parameters to the function, you need to [encode them](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/abi-spec.html#argument-encoding) and append to the transaction data after 4-bytes function selector.  For single argument of type `string` the encoding will be:

```
string offset: 32 bytes
string body length: 32 bytes
string body padded right to the round 32-bytes
```

So if you want to call your `set` function and pass `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"` as a parameter, you need to attach the following data to the transaction:

```
4ed3885e                                                         // 4-bytes function selector
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 // string body offset (32)
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b // string body length (43)
54686520717569636b2062726f776e20666f78206a756d7073206f7665722074 // string body padded
6865206c617a7920646f67000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 // to round 32 bytes
```

Note that offset points to the string length and does not take function selector into account.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake in below. i mean to "set".

Comment: now how can i write set function with parameter?

Comment: Updated the answer